# Drop event happening more than one time in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am implementing Drag and Drop functionality in SWT.

Here is my code snippet

For Drag

```
private class MyDragSourceAdapter extends DragSourceAdapter {

/** The m tree viewer. */
private final TreeViewer treeViewer;

/**
 * Instantiates a new my drag source adapter.
 * 
 * @param treeViewer the tree viewer
 */
public MyDragSourceAdapter(TreeViewer treeViewer) {
  this.treeViewer = treeViewer;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {
  // clean buffer
  // k = null;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
    event.data = "test";
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {

  if (some condition) {
   // do something
    return;
  }
  event.doit = false;
}
}
```

For drop

```
private class MyDropTargetAdapter extends DropTargetAdapter {

@Override
public void dragEnter(DropTargetEvent event) {
  event.detail = DND.DROP_LINK;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void dragOver(DropTargetEvent event) {
  // Do some functionality
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
  event.detail = DND.DROP_NONE;
}
}
```

Some times **"dragOver()"** method called more than one time? So dragging is happening as many times as dragOver() method called.

I want drop operation to stop after first time.

Please help

Comment: This behavior is intended. If you read the JavaDoc, it says, the event occurs if  'the cursor is moving over the drop target'. Listen to the `drop()` event to get informed when the drop.operation is actually performed. The article [DnD in SWT](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html) gives a good overview what the respecive events are meant for.

Comment: Yes, Rüdiger Herrmann you are right, I read Doc, drop method will be called multiple times so I wrote some logic to stop further actions even this method called.

Answer (score 1):

`dragOver()` happens when the mouse is still hovering over the control, before the actual drop happens. You probably mean to override `drop()`. But if you want the drop from stop happening altogether, set the field `detail` on the `DropTargetEvent` to `DND.DROP_NONE`.